# jVectorMap - fill country on button press

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

Using jVectorMap, I would like to have a function that takes the country code as its parameters, then highlights that country on the map. For example:

```
function colorCountry(var code){
   $('#world-map').vectorMap(
      code : '#686868',
   ));
}
```

That is just a mockup; I'm asking here because I have little experience with Javascript / jQuery and haven't been able to find a suitable solution on Google.

I would like the function to simply color the country it is provided with, rather than clear the map so only one country is colored. For example:

```
colorCountry("DE");
colorCountry("US");
```

..would present the user with a map with *both* US and DE colored, rather than just one.

Comment: can you make jsfiddle example for this

Comment: jsfiddle? The code I entered doesn't work, it's just an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#world-map').vectorMap({
   series: {
      regions: [{ values: {
                   "US":"#686868",
                   "DE"："#686868"
                  }, attribute: 'fill' }]
   }
});
```